# Login incorrect on CentOS

Tags: centos, login

I've downloaded a CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511 iso file for testing purposes. I also have Hyper-V on Windows 10.

I loaded the image file and as far as configuring the below there was not much to do and went on to proceed:

[image]

I then click Begin Installation. Afterwards, it requires me to reboot which I did.

After rebooting, I see the below and I just went with the first selection and hit enter:

[image]

After the above, I see the below and don't know what it means and proceeded to wait:

[image]

Finally, I see the below:

[image]

With the above image is where it all falls apart. I know for a fact that I did not set a username yet. However, I did set a root password and that was all. Every attempt I make I get the error message "**Login incorrect**".

Am I doing something wrong? What is required for the login when a username has not been set?

I'm new to Linux and require some assistance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you create a password during installation?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to set password while installation, now you can workaround by resetting root password.

Follow the below procedure:

1 – In the boot grub menu select option to edit.

2 – Select Option 1 to edit (e).

3 – Go to the line of Linux 16 and change `ro` with `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh`.

4 – Now press Control+x to start on single user mode.

5 – Now access the system with this command. >> `chroot /sysroot`

6 – Reset the password. with >> `passwd root`

7 – Update selinux information with >> `touch /.autorelabel`

8 – Exit chroot >> `exit`

9 – Reboot your system >> `reboot`

its Done now you ll be able to access with your newly set passwd...